# GCP- API gateway - how to handle or config 100+ cloud function or cloud run end point via GCP api gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway

We are using multiple cloud function and multiple cloud Run endpoints.
need to config all under one API gateway , but as per Quota limits - only 50 API can be added.
If we have more than 50 endpoints (cloud function and multiple cloud Run endpoints) , how to config that?
Please suggest me the way to solve this problem

Comment: I am also creating a design that will use API GW. My read of 50 APIs is that you can create 50 backend services, like ordering, inventory, etc, up to 50 of those. One could be Cloud Functions, another Cloud Run, etc. Then, I believe the 100 limit on API Configs means each of those can have up to 100 end points defined. That would mean a total of 50x100=5000 end point in all over numerous backend services. I need to very this myself with our Google support engineer but that's how I read it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is create more than one gateway. And put all the gateways after a load balancer in diferent backend services.

So that, you can route the trafic in the load balancer into diferent backend services.

Here are the docs
https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg